# Ever increasing CPU consumption with Haskell and stream-fusion

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, cpu-usage, stream-fusion

Here is a short Haskell program that generates a 440 Hz sound. It uses pulseaudio as an audio backend.

```
import GHC.Float
import Control.Arrow
import Sound.Pulse.Simple
import qualified Data.List.Stream as S
import Data.List

type Time = Double
type Frequency = Double
type Sample = Double
type CV = Double

chunksize = 441 * 2
sampleRate :: (Fractional a) => a
sampleRate = 44100

integral :: [Double] -> [Double]
integral = scanl1  (\acc x -> acc + x / sampleRate)

chunks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks n = S.takeWhile (not . S.null) . S.unfoldr (Just . S.splitAt n)

pulseaudioOutput :: [Sample] -> IO ()
pulseaudioOutput sx = do

    pa <- simpleNew Nothing "Synths" Play Nothing "Synths PCM output"
         (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1) Nothing Nothing

    mapM_ (simpleWrite pa . S.map double2Float) $ chunks 1000 sx

    simpleDrain pa
    simpleFree pa

oscSine :: Frequency -> [CV] ->  [Sample]
oscSine f = S.map sin <<< integral <<< S.map ((2 * pi * f *) . (2**))

music ::[Sample]
music = oscSine 440 (S.repeat 0)

main = do
    pulseaudioOutput music
```

If I compile and run this, I see an ever growing CPU consumption.

If I change "S.splitAt" to "splitAt" in the definition of "chunks", everything is fine.

Can anyone guess why this can be?

Thank you.

### Update

In the following code all three version of chunks can produce the aforementioned behaviour:

```
import GHC.Float
import Control.Arrow
import Sound.Pulse.Simple
import Data.List.Stream

import Prelude hiding ( unfoldr
                      , map
                      , null
                      , scanl1
                      , takeWhile
                      , repeat
                      , splitAt
                      , drop
                      , take
                      )

type Time = Double
type Frequency = Double
type Sample = Double
type CV = Double

chunksize = 441 * 2
sampleRate :: (Fractional a) => a
sampleRate = 44100

integral :: [Double] -> [Double]
integral = scanl1  (\acc x -> acc + x / sampleRate)

chunks :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
--chunks n = takeWhile (not . null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)
--chunks n xs = take n xs : chunks n (drop n xs)
chunks n xs = h : chunks n t
    where
        (h, t) = splitAt n xs

pulseaudioOutput :: [Sample] -> IO ()
pulseaudioOutput sx = do

    pa <- simpleNew Nothing "Synths" Play Nothing "Synths PCM output"
         (SampleSpec (F32 LittleEndian) 44100 1) Nothing Nothing

    mapM_ (simpleWrite pa . map double2Float) $ chunks 1000 sx

    simpleDrain pa
    simpleFree pa

oscSine :: Frequency -> [CV] ->  [Sample]
oscSine f = map sin <<< integral <<< map ((2 * pi * f *) . (2**))

music ::[Sample]
music = oscSine 440 (repeat 0)

main = do
    pulseaudioOutput music
```

I cleaned up the code to avoid mixing plain old lists and stream-fusion lists. The memory / cpu leak is still there. To see that the code is working on old lists, just remove the Prelude import and ".Stream" after "Data.List".

Comment: Basically, lists are not suited for audio samples anyway. It kind of works, but never expect the performance to be good enough for anything nontrivial. (Though [the trivial stuff can already be quite exciting](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11463/mozart-golf-mini-rondo/11514#11514)...)

Comment: Indeed, but I'd like to cross that bridge when I came to it.

If I use plain old lists, the performance is actually pretty OK for what it really does at the hardware level :) 1-2% CPU for a single oscillator is OK in a practical setting, since expensive synthesizer programs can eat up one or two cores for a simple synth patch. (Yes, they're poorly written. Whatever.)

I can actually run a 128th order FIR with using only lists (ok, maybe a Sequence for the coefficients), so the performance is ok for me as long as this stuff is experimental.

Thanks for the link, very nice! :)

Comment: Really, 128th order FIR? So you run an FFT directly on lists, like [user3407776 does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335577/how-to-apply-data-parallelim-on-haskell-fast-fourier-transformation/22336721#22336721)? I mean, cool and everything, that GHC makes lists so fast it's possible, but I can understand _why_! You'd get yet much better performance with tight array chunks, and Haskell's type system is quite able to abstract them away so it looks just as nice as with lists.

Comment: As I told so, I'll cross that bridge what I come to it. This is not about performance, it's just an experiment. This question in particular is about a possible bug in my code or in the stream-fusion library. Currently I'm not interested in other aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `splitAt` on streams that is substituted by the fusion rules (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion-0.1.2.5/docs/Data-Stream.html#g:12) has the following signature:

```
splitAt :: Int -> Stream a -> ([a], [a])
```

From this we can see that since it produces lists and not streams, that obstructs further fusion. The correct thing to do, I think, is to produce either a `splitAt` that generates streams, or better yet to write a `chunks` function directly on streams with the appropriate fusion rules from the list version.

Here is a `splitAt` on streams that I think should be good. You would of course need to pair it with the appropriate rewrite rules from a `splitAt` on lists, and if those rewrite rules get tricky, perhaps write the `chunks` function directly, though it seems a bit tricky to do so as well:

```
splitAt :: Int -> Stream a -> (Stream a, Stream a)
splitAt n0 (Stream next s0)
  | n0 < 0    = (nilStream, (Stream next s0))
  | otherwise = loop_splitAt n0 s0
  where
    nilStream = Stream (const Done) s0
    loop_splitAt  0 !s = (nilStream, (Stream next s))
    loop_splitAt !n !s = case next s of
      Done            -> (nilStream, nilStream)
      Skip    s'      -> loop_splitAt n s'
      Yield x s'      -> (cons x xs', xs'')
        where
          (xs', xs'') = loop_splitAt (n-1) s'
```

Comment: Thank you, even after this much time your explanation has enlightened me. I might give this project of mine a second chance ;)

Comment: @netom, you probably will need to add some inlining annotations here. Based on what `vector` does with similar things, I think probably `{-# INLINE [1] splitAt #-}` and  `{-# INLINE [0] loop_splitAt #-}`. But any time you're dealing with this sort of fusion stuff, you should be sure to profile, profile, profile and spend some time groveling over the Core. I recommend `-ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-signatures`. If you've never seen Core before, it may look a little scary, but it's really fairly similar to Haskell.